# kendoui menu filter / form

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

I would like to have a button and when the user clicks on it a filter form pops down just below the button. I would like to utilize Kendo UI controls to achieve the effect.

In fact, what I need is almost exactly the 'filtering' that can be found on this example:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization

However, I'm not dealing with a grid of data so I can't use that example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different possible implementations. Here I will describe one based on `kendoWindow` since then you have a lot of possible customizations for that filtering form.

This is the HTML that includes the button:

```
<div>
    This is the container that includes a 
    <button id="filter" class="k-button">Filter</button>
    that is used to display a form
</div>
```

And then you define the HTML form. Example:

```
<div id="form">
    <div>Filtering value:<input data-role="autocomplete"/></div>
    <button class="k-button">Filter</button>
</div>
```

Doing the form initialization is:

```
var form = $("#form").kendoWindow({
    title    : "Filter",
    visible  : false,
    modal    : false,
    draggable: false
}).data("kendoWindow");
```

Where initially we set the form as not visible.

You can define it as `modal`, `draggable` or even define the opening and closing effect.

Finally, for opening and placing the form just bellow the button you should:

```
$("#filter").on("click", function(e) {
    // Find clicked button
    var button = $(e.currentTarget);
    // and get its position
    var pos = button.offset();
    // shift down the form to open by the height of the button + 5px (margin)
    pos.top += button.outerHeight() + 5;
    // Apply positioning to the form
    form.wrapper.css(pos);
    // display form
    form.open();
});
```

You can see this here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/mpq6k/

Comment: This got me most of the way there. From there I got rid of the menu title `title: false`. Then I had to attach a click event to the document that would close the window if the event target didn't have the kendo window as an ancestor (which was tricky since DropDownList UL isn't within the window, but somewhere close to the document root). Now I just need to create a dynamic form for the different fields, dataTypes and operators.